# java.text.Normalizer: isNormalized() returns false, but Normalize doesn't change the string

Tags: java, unicode, normalization, unicode-normalization

I just started learning about `java.text.Normalizer`. It seemed pretty straightforward. I've got one of the "weird" dashes to deal with (specifically [U+2013](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E2%80%93#En_dash))

I'd like to convert it to a normal dash character, so I made some quick testing code:

```
import java.text.Normalizer;

public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String weirdDash = "–";
    String normalDash = "-";

    boolean b = Normalizer.isNormalized(weirdDash, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
    if(b == false) {
        System.out.println("Java thinks the weird dash is normal");
        return;
    }
    String normalizedWeirdDash = Normalizer.normalize(weirdDash, Normalizer.Form.NFD);

    if(normalizedWeirdDash.equals(normalDash)) {
        System.out.println("Yay!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Boo! normalized weird dash "+(normalizedWeirdDash.equals(weirdDash) ? "didn't change" : "= " + normalizedWeirdDash));
    }
}
}
```

The output of main() is "Boo! normalized weird dash didn't change"

How is that possible? It means that Normalizer.isNormalized returned false, but then calling  normalize() on the same string (with the same Normalizer.Form) did not change it at all.

Did I miss something?

**EDIT**
This method outputs "true":

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String weirdDash = "–";
        String normalDash = "-";
        String newDash = weirdDash.replaceAll("(\\\u2013)", "-");
        System.out.println(newDash.equals(normalDash));
    }
}
```

So, if all else fails, I can use this. But for curiosity's sake, what's up with Normalizer?

Comment: What do you suppose `isNormalized` means?

Comment: And what do you think Normalizer does?

Comment: Abstractly, My hunch is that if `Normalize.isNormalized(foo, bar)` returns `true` then calling `Normalize.normalize(foo, bar)` would ALWAYS return `foo`, but if it returns `false`, calling `Normalize.normalize(foo, bar)` would ALWAYS return something not equal to `foo`. Makes sense to me anyway. Is that not how it works?

Comment: I think Normalizer converts Unicode characters into their closest non-unicode equivalent. Is that not correct?

Comment: Not at all. Normalizer converts unicode characters to others unicode characters. The point is, there is several unicode representation for "é", and in normalize form, their is only one.

Comment: isNormalized returns true if the string is already normalized.  But your code will print "Java thinks the weird dash is normal" if the string is NOT normalized.

Comment: Yep, Etienne caught that below. Huge typo that basically renders my whole question moot.

Comment: What's up with Normalizer?  Read it's description to understand what it's supposed to do.

Comment: I asked you about it ten minutes ago.

Comment: What Unicode normalization is and does is [pretty well specified and documented](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/). Dunno where you got the idea that it would turn a en-dash into a minus.

Answer (score 1):

> It means that Normalizer.isNormalized returned false

No, it means that Normalizer.isNormalized returned `true`. Re-read your code. Maybe you meant

```
if (b == true) {
```

when you wrote

```
if (b == false) {
```

Comment: You sir, are completely correct. That was a major typo in my code that basically threw off my whole argument

Answer (score 0):

`U+2013` (en-dash) and `U+002D` (minus sign) are two different Unicode characters, *not* two different representations of the same character. Thus, normalization does not change the first into the second.

Besides, `"\u2013"` is already normalized, and `isNormalized()` evaluated to `true` in your code.

Comment: Good eye. Better than mine anyway :)